# Is the cohomology ring of a CW complex computable?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, computational-mathematics

There is a well-developed technology for computing the cohomology groups of a CW complex, cellular cohomology. It reduces the problem of computing cohomology to the two simpler problems of (1) endowing a space with a CW structure and (2) computing the degrees of some maps between spheres. Consequently, the problem of computing the cohomology of a CW complex is *completely solved* and *effectively computable*.

To contrast, the homotopy groups of a CW complex are *not* effectively computable. Famously, even the simple case of the homotopy groups of the spheres is extremely difficult and not completely resolved.

What about the *cup product* structure on cohomology? Is the cohomology ring effectively computable? Is there any "algorithm" to compute the cohomology ring of a CW complex, similar to the "algorithm" of cellular cohomology?

I would guess that the answer to these questions is "yes" because cohomology seems eminently computable. Is it?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense unless you say how you're encoding a CW complex as the input to your algorithm.

Comment: In practical terms the usual difficulty is that you need to replace the diagonal map $X \to X \times X$ with a cellular map.

Comment: @EricWofsey This is probably not clear from my writing, but I'm not looking for an algorithm that you could plug into a computer (maybe the computational-mathematics tag was overkill). I just want a sense for the difficulty of the problem.

Comment: Also, the homotopy groups of spheres (and more generally any simply connected finite simplicial complex) _are_ computable, though not efficiently.  This is a theorem of Brown from the 1950s.

Comment: Oh, I see. So is the problem really to understand the collection of homotopy groups of the spheres as a whole, instead of in any specific instance?

Comment: @user134824: More or less, although my understanding is also that the algorithms known are very inefficient and so if you wanted to compute any specific homotopy group with them it might well take longer than the age of the universe.